# Django rest how to change the lookup id in swagger auto documention?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

[image]
[views.py](https://gitlab.com/jawahar273/bm/blob/186ee38a239b60fd2021547bc1052308a2aa0e37/weather/views.py)

```
    def retrieve(self, request, weather_date=None):
```

as shows in the image of `retrieve()` i have change the argument as `weather_date` but the swagger is generating only `pk` and serializer class is `viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet` and the router in [urls.py](https://gitlab.com/jawahar273/bm/blob/186ee38a239b60fd2021547bc1052308a2aa0e37/weather/urls.py)  is `DefaultRouter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest-swagger introspects the the ModelViewSet class rather than the function signature. That field is based off the lookup_field attribute on view class. Reason being is that object lookups are also used for update, partial update and delete 
ie

```
delete /api/weather/air-pollution/:weather_date
or
patch /api/weather/air-polution/:weather_date
```

The lookup field on this is defaulted to `'id'`. Instead I would over ride the value in your Weather viewset class.

```
class Weather(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
   lookup_field = 'weather_date'
```

Changing this should reflect in your rest swagger docs